# I have a list of items that I need to modify need to figure out a way to replace each ";" with a line break

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Top pretty much says it all. Basically I want to replace every `;` in a list with a line break but I don't know how to input a line break into the replace function built into Word. I'm using MS Word 2007 running on Windows 7 Pro.

Can somebody please assist?

Comment: What do you mean by line break exactly? A hitting the return button?

Comment: Yeah, exactly that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Replace Text (Ctrl H).

Enter `;` into "Find what".

Either enter `^l` (that's "Shift 6" then lower case "L") into "Replace with", or select "More >>" and then select "Manual Line Break" from the "Special" dropdown.

Comment: When I just tried this, the CTRL+1 only sets it to single spacing, but does not actually replace anything when I hit "Replace all". The second part works.

Comment: @KCotreau - That's because you don't enter Ctrl+1 but **type** `^l`. That's "Shift 6" then lower case "L"

Comment: Cool, that did work (of course, you know that). I am glad you clarified since I didn't even realize it was a lowercase "L".

Comment: Confirmed that this does the trick, thanks for your help ChrisF.

Answer (score 2):

In the `Find and Replace` dialog, with your cursor positioned in the `Replace with` textbox, click on the `More` button, and then click on the `Special` button on the bottom of the dialog box.  `Manual Line Break` is the choice that you're looking for.